# Startup circuit in flyback power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I'm looking into this reference design: https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidrlf7

When U1 turns on the pin 5 outputs a 32 kHz PWM signal which is supposed to turn Q4 on and subsequently turn Q3 off during startup. When Q4 turns on D20 should be shorted, right? I'm doing some tests in a design like this and generally speaking it works, I get stable output voltage. However, what I don't understand is the voltage across D20. When Q4 turns on I should read nearly zero at D20, but I always read 24V even when U1 is running. Am I misunderstanding something?

[image]

Comment: Where are you measuring with respect to and do you have a link to the full TI project? What you say sounds reasonable.

Comment: It sounds like Q4 is not turning on in your case.  The supply will still run, but you will be wasting a lot of power in the startup circuit.  It may fail eventually if not thermally designed for continuous operation.  To troubleshoot look at the gate voltage of Q4 to see why it’s not turning on.

Comment: List all relevant U1 readings